# WP_Post object to string conversion error, when register custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Seen a bunch or responses that talk about post ID, and menus... but this is a brand new blog. I am building a plugin, but when I register a custom post type I get this error...

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1280

```
register_post_type('car_post', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Car Content'
    ),
    'singular_label' => 'Car Content',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_in_menu' => 'car-post',
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "car_post"),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', 'comments' )
    )
);
```

Anyone have an idea on what could possibly be causing that? If I comment out the custom post block... then no errors are thrown.

Comment: What do you mean by _custom post block_?

Comment: Just meant the block of code for registering the custom post type... just a case of doing too many things at once. I should have explained that better.

Comment: Its working fine here. Could you show more context of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Custom post types are registered this way.

```
<?php

        add_action( 'init', 'my_post_type' );


        function my_post_type() {
            register_post_type('car_post', array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Car Content'
            ),
            'singular_label' => 'Car Content',
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'show_in_menu' => 'car-post',
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => "car_post"),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', 'comments' )
            )
            );
        }


 ?>
```

Comment: It should work that way what OP currently has now. :)

Comment: Yeah, it should. Besides, I have the action in there anyway. And it is contained in a function...